# Jboss 7.1.1 on suse linux using its logger when slf4j is used instead of web-app local log file

Tags: jboss, log4j, slf4j

Jboss 7.1.1 on suse linux sp2 using its logger when slf4j is used instead of web-application local log file. And those logs are logged inside console.log. And this casues performance hit as sysouts/syserr also go to console.log.

In our web application one module is using slf4j + log4j. But when jboss started it was using slf4j + org.jboss.logmanager instead of slf4j + log4j for that module.

Answer (score 1):

Added below entry in exclusion list of jboss-deployment-descriptor which is placed at webContext\WEB-INF\ location.
< module name="org.sfl4l" / >